# What's wrong with my SQL query? Getting the "values does not match table definition" error

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

Table: Users

Columns:

```
UserID: int (PK Identity 1,1)
TypeID: int
Email: varchar(100)
Password: varchar(300)
LastName: varchar(20)
FirstName: varchar(20)
Street: varchar(20)
Municipality: varchar(50)
City: varchar(20)
Phone: char(7)
Mobile: char(11)
Status: varchar(20)
DateAdded: datetime
DateModified: datetime
```

This is my query

```
INSERT INTO Users VALUES (2, 
                          'phil@gmail.com',  
                          'password', 
                          'Reavis',
                          'Phil',
                          'Street', 
                          'Municipality', 
                          'City',
                          '1234567', 
                          '12345678910', 
                          'Active', 
                          '2018-09-09 08:00:00', 
                          '2018-01-01 09:00:00' )
```

I keep getting the Error: Msg 213, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.

Comment: [MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/) and [SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-reference) are different software packages produced by different companies. Even if both of them implement SQL, they extend it in different ways and sometimes they use different syntax conventions that render the queries incompatible between them. Please use only the tags that match the software you are using.

Comment: I've removed the MySql tag that seems irrelevant here. The error message (in the form of msg, level, state) is clearly what SQL Server returns. Also `IDENTITY` is MSSQL-specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query simply doesn't provide enough values to fill all fields. In such cases you can provide the list of fields to fill with the values provided in the `VALUES` clause:

```
INSERT INTO Users (
    TypeID, Email, Password, LastName,
    FirstName, Street, Municipality, City,
    Phone, Mobile, Status,
    DateAdded, DateModified
) VALUES (
     2, 'phil@gmail.com', 'password', 'Reavis',
    'Phil', 'Street', 'Municipality', 'City',
    '1234567', '12345678910', 'Active',
    '2018-09-09 08:00:00', '2018-01-01 09:00:00'
)
```

Read about the syntax of the [`INSERT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/insert-transact-sql) statement.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add column names to the insert statement, for example:

```
INSERT INTO Users (email, password, ...) VALUES ('email@domain.com', 'password');
```

Answer (score -1):

You missed  TypeID, second parameter is email

try it

```
INSERT INTO Users VALUES (2, null,'phil@gmail.com', 'password', 'Reavis',
                                 'Phil','Street', 'Municipality', 'City',
                                 '1234567', '12345678910', 'Active', 
                                 '2018-09-09 08:00:00', '2018-01-01 09:00:00' )
```

Comment: He didnt missed. He just didnt provide the identity column